# Is the "GTA: ELC" entry in my Steam library spam?

Tags: steam, grand-theft-auto-iv

Ever since buying a GTA collection on Steam there's an entry in the library called "Grand Theft Auto: Episodes from Liberty City". I finally tried it today, only to get some [bleep]ing [bleep] about paying 800 "credits" to play it. Does this mean the entry in the library is just DLC spam?

[On a side note, why is "dlc" not a valid tag?]

Comment: Regarding the DLC tag, [it was removed](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8336/burn-dlc-as-per-cleanup-thread-2013-14).

Comment: Do you have Grand Theft Auto IV and Games for Windows Live installed? Episodes from Liberty City is an addon for GTA IV, and GTA IV requires GFWL to be installed.

Answer (score 3):

I saw somewhere on Steam awhile back that this is a known issue with Episodes From Liberty City when you try to play it on Windows 8.

Supposedly, installing a [standalone copy of Games for Windows Live](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/LIVE/PC/DownloadClient) fixes it, but I'm not in a position to try it.